# the zero element in Hom

Tags: continuity, sheaf-theory

Definition.(from P276 of Introduction to Homological Algebra by Rotman)

Let *S* = {*E, p, X*} and *S'* = {*E', p', X*} be etale-sheaves over a space *X*. An etale map *f: S $\to$ S'* is a continuous map *f: *E* $\to$ *E'** such that *p'f* = *p* and each *f*|*E$_x$* is a homomorphism. Then Hom$_e$$_t$ is an additive abelian group if we define *f + g: E $\to$ E'* by *(f + g)(e) = f(e) + g(e)*.

I can't see how the zero in the Hom group is continuous. If I am correct, $\mathrm{0}$(e) = 0 where 0 is the zero element in the abelian group E'$_x$ where x = *p*(e). Should I find an open set in *E'*? Any help would be appreciated!